# Update the state in React app replacing the old array with new sorted array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and just started learning. I'm trying to sort the object based on the price of product. but when I try to update the state it wont change although when I do console.log() I can see the sorted products but it simply wont update on screen. I'm attaching the code below. any help would be appreciated.

When I open the app. I see all my products. but when I use the select box to sort the products it simply shows me the same products without sorted. The event is triggered. but I doubt the way I'm updating the state is wrong.

```
import './main.css'
import Filters from './components/Filters'
import Products from './components/Products'
import { useState } from 'react';


function App() {
  const [products,setProducts]=useState([
    {product_id:'1',product_name:"Razer Deathadder expert ergonomic mousepad",product_price:"20",product_path:"img/razer-deathadder-expert-ergonomic-original-imaf2z3xngbchfaz.jpeg"},
    {product_id:'2',product_name:"Zotac gtx 1080 graphics card",product_price:"320",product_path:"img/grap.jpg"},
    {product_id:'3',product_name:"Kingston 250 gb SSD ",product_price:"90",product_path:"img/ssd.jpg"},
    {product_id:'4',product_name:"Ryzen Processor",product_price:"250",product_path:"img/ry.jpg"}
    ]);


   let sortedProducts=[]
    const sortProducts=(e)=>{
      const sortBy=String(e.target.value);
      switch(sortBy){
      case 'plh': // sorting based on price low to high
      sortedProducts=products.sort((x,y)=>{
      return Number(x.product_price)-Number(y.product_price);
      });
      setProducts(sortedProducts); // I'm chaning the state here with my newly sorted array but its not rendering on screen
      break;
      case 'phl':
      sortedProducts=products.sort((x,y)=>{
      return Number(y.product_price)-Number(x.product_price);
      });
      setProducts(sortedProducts); // I'm chaning the state here with my newly sorted array but its not rendering on screen
      break;
      }
    }
   
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
      <Filters sortProducts={sortProducts}/>
      <Products products={products} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Products component

```
import Product from './Product'

function Products({products}) {
    return (
        <div className="product-container">
         {products.map(element => (
         <Product product={element}/>
    ))}
        </div>  
    );
  }
  
  export default Products;
```

Comment: Please show the ```Products``` component

Comment: @TwoHorses I did please check now.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in something like codesandbox

Comment: In the ```App``` component can you render this: ```<div className="App">{JSON.stringify(products)}</div>``` and see if the products re render with the updated value? (Or just provide a codesandbox reproduction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your sorted products in state with using spread operators

Try:-

```
setProducts([...sortedProducts]);
```

See [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/priyank-react-utj1b)